# how to create left side image and right side content

Tags: html, css, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

This is for desktop mode image under content.in tab mode, I need an image after content like
left side image and right side content. I am using bootstrap 3 and sass.

I have created like this for tab mode but its not working properly for me:

```css
     div:nth-child(2),div:nth-child(3){
                position: absolute;
                right: 51px;
                top: 95px;
                width:50%;
               
            }
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-3  col-xs-12 hiw-cols-first">
          <picture>
            <img class="hiw-tab-images" src="images/p-tab.png">
            <img class="hiw-images" src="images/r-product.png">
          </picture>
          <div class="hiw_heading">Obtain your Product</div>
          <div class="hiw-subpara">dable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
         of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
            opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
               Many desktop </div>
     </div>
```

i have done for desktop mode but i need help for tab mode please anyone help to do this.

Comment: hope this helpful to you https://jsfiddle.net/9k8w1fpq/4/

Comment: i need left side image and right side content in tablet mode.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need above CSS. You are using bootstrap so, you can simply do it using row and col classes. **Try this**

```
<div class="col-md-3  col-xs-12 hiw-cols-first">
      <div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-4">
 <picture>
        <img class="hiw-tab-images" src="images/p-tab.png">
        <img class="hiw-images" src="images/r-product.png">
      </picture>
 </div>          
 <div class="col-8">
  <div class="hiw_heading">Obtain your Product</div>
      <div class="hiw-subpara">dable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
     of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
        opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
           Many desktop </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Since you are using bootstrap 3 you need to add **md, sm with col class**. Updated code with bootstrap 3

```
<div class="col-md-3  col-xs-12 hiw-cols-first">
      <div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
 <picture>
        <img class="hiw-tab-images" src="images/p-tab.png">
        <img class="hiw-images" src="images/r-product.png">
      </picture>
 </div>          
 <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
  <div class="hiw_heading">Obtain your Product</div>
      <div class="hiw-subpara">dable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
     of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
        opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
           Many desktop </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/e5zro9qg/1/

Comment: Have you added correct bootstrap link to your project?

Comment: please can you write css or sass for this. this is not for single cols i need for this more than 3 cols

Comment: You don't need css for this. All these classes are available in bootstrap 3. So, you can modify the classes based on number of grids you require or type of screen size. This link might be helpful for you  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Please check the below snippet:

```css
.hiw-cols-first {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3  col-xs-12 hiw-cols-first">
          <picture>
             <img class="hiw-tab-images" src="images/p-tab.png">
             <img class="hiw-images" src="images/r-product.png">
          </picture>
          <div>
          <div class="hiw_heading">Obtain your Product</div>
          <div class="hiw-subpara">dable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
         of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
            opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
               Many desktop </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its actually right way but its not working for me.